# Is there an AngularJS way to have a press of a key call a routine in my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm expecting someone is going to suggest I use jQuery (which I have loaded) but just to be sure before I look into how to implement can someone tell me if there is another way that I can make the hitting of a key (the right arrow key) call a javascript function in my controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect keydown or keypress event in angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360202/how-can-i-detect-keydown-or-keypress-event-in-angular-js)

Comment: press anywhere on the document?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### If you want to listen to events on the document

- register an event listener when the scope is instantiated
- make sure you also destroy it when the scope is destroyed
- I also tried to use `keypress` but it seems to ignore the arrow keys.
- Read more: [jQuery Keypress Arrow Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys)
- Maybe you'll need to use e.which: [Javascript .keyCode vs. .which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which)

```js
var handler = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 39) {
      console.log('right arrow');
      // $scope.doSomething();
    }      
};

var $doc = angular.element(document);

$doc.on('keydown', handler);
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
  $doc.off('keydown', handler);
})
```

---

#### What about `ng-keypress` / `ng-keydown` :

- **ng-keypress** has a the same problem with arrow keys ( It just uses `element.on('keypress',`).
- **ng-keydown** will probably work as well for you.

#### What is the angular way?

- **"Angular way"** is a subjective term, although most angular experts would agree to 
  some level.
- Sometimes, angular let you choose between different ways and they are all fine.
- It always depends on how your app is structured and what you want to achieve.
- Angular.js provides some toys for convenience ( the built-in directives ), it doesn't mean you should always prefer using them.
- My guidelines are **decoupled** / **simple** / **clean** code as much as possible.
- Declarative not always means decoupled / simple / clean ( hmm... XML )
- If your whole code lives inside a controller so why decouple it with a specific template that must declare `ng-event` with `a specific function`?!
- I would always consider creating custom directives for events & handlers (but again it depends on the use case).
- As you master angular.js (learn the internals) you will find "your own angular way".

Comment: Is this better than using ng-keypress?  I am thinking ng-keypress may be a more "Angular" way of doing it. Can you let me know your opion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-keypress="callFunction($event)"`

And in function

```
$scope.callFunction = function(eventNew) {
  if (eventNew.which==39)
    alert('Right arrow key pressed');
}
```

Comment: Is ng-keypress new. I saw the link pointed to in the comment and did not see mention of it.

Comment: Where would you suggest I place this directive if I want to catch the keypress on any part of the page?

Comment: You can place it on the body. Like <body ng-keypress="callFunction($event)"> </body>

Comment: What if this is specific only to a specific part of the page? e.g. template within a modal popup. Any way to keep it clean and together with the part it is relevant to?